# Javascript in HTML file won't output variable

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a simple HTML form in Mockup.html asking for your name. Clicking the "say my name" button should have the same html file output the name provided... but it doesn't.

Am I missing something?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script language="javascript">
    function $_GET(q, s) {
      s = s ? s : window.location.search;
      var re = new RegExp('&' + q + '(?:=([^&]*))?(?=&|$)', 'i');
      return (s = s.replace(/^?/, '&').match(re)) ? (typeof s[1] == 'undefined' ? '' : decodeURIComponent(s[1])) : undefined;
    }

    var usersName = $_GET('username');
    if (typeof(usersName) != 'undefined') {
      document.write('<h1>Hi there, ' + usersName + '</h1>');
    }
  </script>

  <form>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="submit" value="Say my name" />
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

I can see the form, the url bar updates to reflect the variable input, but the page won't display it.

Note that I DO NOT want to upload this to a web server. The html file should run from a local harddrive without internet access.

Comment: @Shreyas — The first line of the function checks to see if `s` is defined and gets a value for it if it isn't.

Comment: @Tibrogargan — The script doesn't try to read the DOM at all, so that's nonsense.

Comment: The issue is not the function, it is your regular expression,

Comment: Is there a reason you are using regex rather than `URLSearchParams`?